# Layout diferente para paisagem

Tags: ios, swift-3, xcode-8

boa tarde.
Não estou sabendo fazer um layout diferente,específico para paisagem...mas queria fazer isso em storyboard não em código , alguém ai sabe?Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia.. :)
Para alterar as medidas do storyboard eu normalmente faço o seguinte:
**1º** - Seleciono o StoryBoard.
**2º** - Vou no lado DIREITO e seleciono o icone Show the size inspector.
**3º** - Na propriedade SIMULATED SIZE mudo para FreeForm e ai altero as dimensões do
StoryBoard.. Deixo ele ate com cara de PAISAGEM...

Espero que eu tenha entendido direito sua duvida...
Qualquer coisa é só falar
Abraços :)

Comment: Valeu amigo!vou tentar agora mesmo e já te falo!

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia..
Outra forma que me dei conta agora é a que mostro na imagem abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na parte circulada abaixo(canto inferior esquerdo) da para colocar o viewcontroller em modo paisagem.
E para ilustrar a primeira resposta que dei, circulei o canto superior direito 
para demonstrar onde fica a propriedade que tinha falado anteriormente.
Qualquer coisa é só falar.
Abraços :)

Comment: Então acho que não deixei muito claro o que eu quero....na verdade deixar o view Controller em modo paisagem eu sei eu só não sei como fazer um layout diferente do modo retrato.Por exemplo vamos supor que eu tenha duas views pequenas em modo retrato mas em modo paisagem eu queria que essas views fiquem um pouco mais esticadas por exemplo....quero fazer um layout totalmente diferente em paisagem entendeu?Obrigado.

Comment: Consegui agora!fui em add new constraints e adicionei 4 constantes e logo em seguida fui em vary for traits e fixei essas mudanças para retrato e depois fiz a mesma coisa para paisagem.Mas obrigado pela ajuda , valeu!

Comment: Isso ai.. Depois que tu fez o primeiro comentário entendi :)... Se tu tivesse falado antes teria te falado para fazer esses passos.. :) Qualquer coisa é so falar.. Sou novo nisso (swift) mas estou gostando muito :) Abraços

Comment: Oi Ricardo!blz?então eu resolvi o problema de fazer um layout pra cada orientação : um pra retrato e outro pra paisagem , até ai tudo bem mas agora surgiu outo problema rs....Não estou conseguindo colocar essa alteração pra todos os dispositivos entendeu ....por exemplo quando seleciono o iPhone 4s em storyboard e vou em vary for traits ai a mudança não serve para iPads , por exemplo , não aparecem os iPads na lista de dispositivos quando clico em vary for traits e depois em width entendeu.Qualquer ajuda agradeço!Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Danilo...
Cara eu nem tinha percebido o iPad...
Na realidade se você notar as duas primeiras imagens que postei eu normalmente
não trabalho com o AUTOLAYOUT habilitado...
Quando habilitei o AutoLayout ai vi que apareceu a opçao iPad.
Tentei fazer uma tela simples.. e usando as constraints fazer ela ficar com uma boa estetica em varios dispositivos inclusive iPad. Também tentei usar o VARY FIR TRAITS como você menciona...Cara, ficou uma cagalhadopança só.
Então deletei a view e comecei novamente do zero.
AutoLayaute habilitado, Use Trait Variations habilitado
Coloquei um VC com dimensoes do iphoneSE.
coloquei os objetos. Arrumei eles do jeito que eu queria.
Usei na palheta SHOW THE SIZE INSPECTOR a propriedade AUTORESINZIG de cada
objeto para "ANCORA-LOS" da forma como queria.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois ajeitar todo o vc rodei em varios formatos..
Ficou tudo legal...Tanto em Paissagem com em Retrato.
Abaixo coloquei um print 
ipone SE - retrato e paisagem
ipone 5 - retrato e paisagem
ipone 7 - retrato e paisagem
Ipad pro 12.9 inch - retrato e paisagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Era essa a dificuldade??? Eu entendi direito a questão??? :)
Se for isso e você quiser eu posso te enviar o StoryBoard. 
Qualquer coisa é só falar. 
Abraços.

Comment: Fala Ricardo!então ...é quase isso mas agora só esta faltando mesmo eu fazer as mudanças para iPad .No caso que vc colocou ai existem dois objetos um amarelo e outro azul certo?O que não estou conseguindo fazer é alterar por exemplo em retrato deixar o objeto amarelo em cima e o azul embaixo mas em paisagem trocar isso deixar o azul em cima e o amarelo embaixo.Isso eu consigo fazer para os dispositivos que são celulares iPhone 4s , SE , 7 e 7 plus , mas para iPad não consigo pois estou usando vary for traits pra utilizar isso mas no caso do iPad não da.Qualquer coisa me de um toque valeu!

Comment: Vi aqui questões parecidas com a minha e estou achando que não é possível fazer layouts diferentes para iPad pelo menos em storyboard.Vou fazer na parte do código mesmo vai ser o jeito.Mas caso consigo ai me fala heim rs....valeu Ricardo !!

Comment: Bom dia Danilo.. Entendi o que o que você quer fazer. Mas fiquei com uma curiosidade. Nas imagens acima eu coloquei 3 OBJETOS. Acima do objeto AMARELO tem um BUTTON VERDE..Seguindo o exemplo que você deu..Quando fosse IPAD PAISSAGEM o AMARELO Desce e o AZUL SOBE..Onde o botao FICARIA??.. Abraços..

Comment: Bom dia Ricardo!o botão verde poderia ficar no centro por exemplo....estou apanhando aqui para esta ferramenta viu nunca vi rs